# Openstack Instance does not use the entire hard disk

Tags: openstack, ubuntu-10.04

I created new vm instance using "Ubuntu Server 10.04 LTS (Lucid Lynx) - 32 bits" image and m1.small falvour which has 20 GB Disk (OpenStack Icehouse). When i logging to the vm and run df -h , I found that the VM does not use the entire assigned HD. The command results are shown as the following:

```
Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/vda1             1.4G  595M  721M  46% /
none                 1005M  144K 1005M   1% /dev
none                 1007M     0 1007M   0% /dev/shm
none                 1007M   36K 1007M   1% /var/run
none                 1007M     0 1007M   0% /var/lock
none                 1007M     0 1007M   0% /lib/init/rw
```

The "fdisk -l" shows the DH size is 20 GB:

```
Disk /dev/vda: 21.5 GB, 21474836480 bytes
4 heads, 32 sectors/track, 327680 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 128 * 512 = 65536 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x000cb9da

Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/vda1   *          17       32768     2096128   83  Linux
```

I need the vm to take the full space assigned to it. Any idea how could I fix it? I want the solution to be applied on each vm I create, so I do not want to manually update the VM after instantiation. I also must use 10.04 image ( can not upgrdate to 14.04)

Comment: mike, can you please check if its running a live os? My guess is the image is not installed.

Comment: What do you mean by live os? I did not get your point. Could you please explain more?

Comment: From where you have taken the image? is this an iso or .img file? Please give more information on how you have uploaded and installed. Because if you just launch any image without installing it will be running in ram . To confirm this please save any file , reboot and test. Also go through http://docs.openstack.org/image-guide/content/ch_obtaining_images.html

Comment: I am using ubuntu 10.04 cloud image (http://uec-images.ubuntu.com/releases/10.04/release/ubuntu-10.04-server-cloudimg-i386-disk1.img) and  I have launched my instance using dashboard . the files stay on HD even after the restart . It is only the image HD does not resize by openstack correctly for some reason.

Comment: You might checkout the answer to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36839303/partitioning-of-instance-in-openstack

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is the image.  I grabbed that one and ran it up, it's pretty simple to run a

`sudo resize2fs /dev/vda1`

which will resize the filesystem to the size of the partition, which seems to be 2GB.  Beyond that, you have to increase the partition size.  For that I think you're probably best off using `virt-resize`, there are some good howto's out there e.g. [askubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/107228/how-to-resize-virtual-machine-disk), in essence:

- SSH into your openstack controller node
- `source keystonerc_admin` (or whatever yours may be called)
- `nova list --all-tenants | grep <instance_name>`  or just grab the server guid from horizon
- `nova show <server_guid>` and note which nova host your machine is running on. Also note the instance name (e.g. instance-00000adb)
- SSH into that nova node
- `virsh dumpxml instance-00000adb` and look for the image file. On mine, this is `/var/lib/nova/instances/<server_guid>/disk` but that may not always be the case?
- `yum install libguestfs-tools`
- `truncate -r /var/lib/nova/instances/d887249a-0d95-473e-b4f2-41f71df4dbb5/disk /var/lib/nova/instances/d887249a-0d95-473e-b4f2-41f71df4dbb5/disk.new`
- `truncate -s +2G /var/lib/nova/instances/d887249a-0d95-473e-b4f2-41f71df4dbb5/disk.new`
- `virt-resize --expand /dev/sda1 /var/lib/nova/instances/d887249a-0d95-473e-b4f2-41f71df4dbb5/disk /var/lib/nova/instances/d887249a-0d95-473e-b4f2-41f71df4dbb5/disk.new`
- `mv disk disk.old ; mv disk.new disk`

NB - mine didn't quite work when I booted that up again, not got time to investigate yet but it can't be far off that, and hopefully this helps.

Once you've managed to boot that up again, then you can shut it down and create a snapshot from horizon. You can then use that snapshot just like any other image, and launch all subsequent VMs directly from there.

HTH.