# partitioning of instance in OpenStack

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox, openstack, partitioning

I uploaded a virtual box image in vdi format to OpenStack. I added a flavor of 100 G size to the instance created using that .vdi image. But it still showing the 15 G size allocated in virtual box. I dont know how to partition the disk to use the size provided by the OpenStack flavor.

```
# df -h
```

is as follows

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/vda1        15G  4,4G  9,3G  32% /
none            4,0K     0  4,0K   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
udev            2,0G  4,0K  2,0G   1% /dev
tmpfs           396M  824K  395M   1% /run
none            5,0M     0  5,0M   0% /run/lock
none            2,0G  144K  2,0G   1% /run/shm
none            100M   40K  100M   1% /run/user
```

And

```
# fdisk /dev/vda1
```

is as follows

```
Device contains neither a valid DOS partition table, nor Sun, SGI or OSF disklabel

Building a new DOS disklabel with disk identifier 0xe682a7ff.
Changes will remain in memory only, until you decide to write them.
After that, of course, the previous content won't be recoverable.

Warning: invalid flag 0x0000 of partition table 4 will be corrected by w(rite)

Command (m for help): p

Disk /dev/vda1: 15.8 GB, 15793651712 bytes
16 heads, 63 sectors/track, 30602 cylinders, total 30846976 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0xe682a7ff

 Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System

Command (m for help):
```

How I need to partition the Virtual machine disk to get the entire 100 Gb size??

Comment: Duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31295416/openstack-instance-does-not-use-the-entire-hard-disk

Answer (score 0):

The partition and filesystem is not extended automatically.

Hint: in your question you use fdisk on the *partition* /dev/vda1 instead of the disk /dev/vda.

You have to do two steps if you want to use the existing partition layout:

1. Increase the size of a partition. There are many documentations available in the internet; example: [Parted: Growing a partition into unused space](https://www.gnu.org/software/parted/manual/html_node/parted_31.html).
2. Increase the size of the filesystem. The command that is needed here depends on your filesystem. If you are using ext[234] you can use `resize2fs /dev/vda1`.

As an alternative you can create a new partition in the empty space (using e.g. `fdisk /dev/vda` and then the command `n` for new), create a new file system on the new partition and mount it - don't forget to add it to `/etc/fstab` that is gets mounted automatically after the next boot.